# Package not found in Application.java in flutter FlutterFirebaseMessaging plugin

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working with firebase messaging. I followed the steps as given in readme of the plugin. But my application .java is giving an error.

Application.java

```
package com.app.demoapp;
import com.transistorsoft.flutter.backgroundfetch.BackgroundFetchPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    BackgroundFetchPlugin.setPluginRegistrant(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
  }
}
```

Error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);                                                     
                                   ^                                                                               
  symbol:   method setPluginRegistrant(Application)                                                                
  location: class FlutterFirebaseMessagingService                                                                  
1 error
```

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem and so far I have not found any solution

**but If you want just show notification with out handle it in background and just lunch app when click on it**

remove     `FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);`and the notification will work fine as **Notification messages** type

if you don't know about Notification type in fcm

refer to [Message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

> With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients:
>
> 1- Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages."
> These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically.
>
> 2- Data messages, which are handled by the client app.

so we use Notification messages here until find solution for handle Data messages

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the instructions file is outdated, it was missing a very important step that you can check at the [github repository README](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/111c5b02945b3668016bb55b14e88a637769a1b3/packages/firebase_messaging/README.md#optionally-handle-background-messages)

> Add the com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging dependency in your app-level build.gradle file that is typically located at /android/app/build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
  // ...

  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just set with

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;


public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements 
PluginRegistrantCallback {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
}

@Override
public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
}
}
```

And make FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegisttrant java

Comment: No Application class is needed to be created inside android now for FCM.